# Помощь в API скриптов Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, api

Не понимаю порой с чего начинать писать код, банально хочу заставить объект двигать, знаю какие компоненты отвечают за это, но не понимаю как реализовать ту или иную систему. Дайте пинка как начать писать
p.s я из рядом только только начавших изучать юнити как движок, но базовые понятия в программировании имею( Базовые )

Comment: Методы движения которые указаны в мануале Юнити использовал, код понимаю, копипастил проверял,работает.
Удаляю код, пытаюсь сам написать - ничего...

Comment: Видео уроки смотри. Даже Гошу Дударя можешь смотреть по началу, главное потом не увлечься.

Answer (score 0):

тут есть 4 способа как это сделать может тебе 1 из них подойдет

вот мои 3 для 3D
в видео все 4 но для 2D

[видео(не моё)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Bhy8ySbews)

1.Translate

```
public Vector3 dir;//или Vector2 (это направление)
public float speed = 1f;//скорость передвижения    

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Translate(dir.normalized * speed);
}
```

2.Lerp

```
Vector3 StartPos;//или Vector2 (позиция)
public Vector3 End;//или Vector2 (позиция)
public float step;//скорость передвижения    
float progress;

void Start()
{
    Start = transform.position;
}    

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Start, End, progress);//или Vector2
    progress += step;
}
```

3.Rigidbody

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public Vector3 dir;//или Vector2 (это направление)
public float acceleration= 1f;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(dir.normalized * acceleration);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]